# Swift, Type 'list.Type' has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
import UIKit

var party: Party = Party()

struct list
{
    var id = "id"
    var startDate = "11/11/1111"
    var name = "name"
    var address = "address"
}

class Party: NSObject
{
    var lists = list[]()    <-- this one has "Type 'list.Type' has no subscript members"

    func addParty(startDate:Date, name:String, address:String)
    {
        lists.append(list(startDate:startDate, name:name, address:address))
    }
}
```

Hi, I am very new to swift and iOS xcode. I was following youtube tutorial on making todo list, but the line where it says var lists = list is giving me error. Does anyone recognize what is wrong with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct array initializer syntax is

```
var lists = [list]()
```

However your code will not compile because `startDate` is declared as `String` but a `Date` parameter is passed.

Declare `startDate` as current `Date` - which is the new native date struct in Swift 3

```
var startDate = Date()
```

or change `addParty`

```
func addParty(startDate:String, name:String, address:String)
```

You have to change the initializer anyway because the implicit memberwise initializer requires to pass **all** parameters

```
lists.append(list(id:"id", startDate:startDate, name:name, address:address))
```

PS: Please consider the Swift naming convention that classes, structs and enums start with a capital letter.

PPS: If the tutorial suggests all that newbie mistakes look for a better tutorial

Comment: Thank you! but what can I do with Date? I have researched but there were only about NSDate, not Date on the website. How do I use Date type?

Comment: Im sorry, but if I put list inside square bracket, lists.append doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Your `list` is struct and can't give you element by subscript. Just replace

```
var lists = list[]()
```

with

```
var lists = list()
```

or
`var lists = [list()]` if you want to create an array of lists